# PHP wont print out query result

Tags: php, html

Hello i am new to working with PHP and for some reason, the code i have typed seems sound but it will not print out the result i want, can any one show me what is wrong? Thank you. The code is below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table>
    <?php
    require_once('DB.php');
    $db = DB::connect("mysql://xxxxxxxxxx");
    if(DB::iserror($db)){
      die($db->getMessage());
    }

    $query = "select FacName from faculty where Department = 'Mathematics & Computer Science';";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
        print "$cname: $cvalue\t";
    }
    print "\r\n";
    }
      ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Connection works but fro security reasons i will not place the actual connection.

Comment: you can put some `echo` controlls to see until where your code is running (or debug it). I would test the query manually to see that it's really returning something and I suppose this is just a playground/test if not check `mysqli` or `pdo` and use prepared statements and parameterized queries. PS: the html tag `table` is also weird used.

Comment: you are using mysql_* that have been removed since PHP7 and was long deprecated before. Switch to mysqli_* or PDO instead and use prepared statements.

Comment: also your html is completely invalid and you should also fix it (i.e. the table tag without an actual table)

Comment: also, enable error reporting and see if your query is returning any result